# amazon ec2 ami backup did not backup /mnt/ partition

Tags: amazon-ec2

i created an amazon ec2 ubuntu m1.small instance and then created an ami to back it up, when i loaded that ami as a spot instance and booted it, it did not have any contents in /mnt parition.

So while creating ami backup why did it skip /mnt? is this /mnt part of EBS??

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# <file system>                                 <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
LABEL=uec-rootfs                                       /               ext4    defaults        0       0
/dev/xvda2      /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0      2
/dev/xvda3      none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0       0
root@ip-10-101-59-62:/mnt/www#
```

since /mnt holds all my websites and mysql data, how can this be added to the ami instance?

Answer (score 0):

No, `/mnt` is the ephemeral data store that gets wiped on reboot.  You really shouldn't store anything in there that you want to survive.  Make your root partition bigger and put all your data in there, or create a separate EBS instance and mount it somewhere else.

Comment: what if i convert it to an EBS instance and then use /mnt within the EBS instance will that be OK? EBS should not delete the data right?

Comment: Like I said, `/mnt` is the ephemeral data.  You can create a separate EBS instance and put your data there.